# GetIpNetTable alternative for IPv6

Tags: c++, network-programming, ipv6

I am trying to discover devices connected within a local area network. I have been successful using the GetIpNetTable function. However, this only returns IPv4 devices and I need to detect devices using IPv6 as well (such as mobile phones connected to the network). Is there a way that this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`GetIpNetTable2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814420(v=vs.85).aspx) function, which can return both the IPv4 ARP table and the IPv6 neighbor table or both, depending on which address family you pass to it. This function requires Windows Vista/2008 or later, and there is absolutely nothing you can do on XP or earlier (except upgrade).